# How do I read a csv file in a Qt Desktop App (widget) and render into a widget table?

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

I normaly read a csv file with `<fstream>` lib and save that info in a `vector<MyStruct>` lib but on this kind of project we have to use something call `<QFile>` and `<QTextStream>` and I don't really know how to use it, even that freaky vector `QStringList` -what a headache-.

I want to render a csv into a widget table and save all info in a vector. this is the struct

```
struct Person
    {
       QString name;
       int age;
       double salary;
    };
```

and my csv structure is like:

```
name,age,salary
name,age,salary
name,age,salary
```

this is my code until now

```
persons[0].name = "Victor Ramos";
persons[0].age= 10;
persons[0].salary= 10000.0;
persons[1].name = "Ana Ramos";
persons[1].age= 15;
persons[1].salary= 12000.0;
int fila;
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
fila = ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1;
ui->tableWidget->setItem(fila, NOMBRE, new QTableWidgetItem(nombre));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(fila, EDAD, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(edad)));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(fila, SALARIO, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(salario)));
```

Normaly I would do this if I were working with a simple console app

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    vector<Person> persons; Person p;
    istream file('myFile.csv');
    string line;
    if(!file.is_open()){ return 1; }else{
        while(!file.eof()){
            getLine(file, line, ',');
            p.name = line;
            getLine(file, line, ',';
            p.edad = stoi(line);
            getLine(file, line);
            //string to float recive a string a return a float
            p.salary = stringToFloat(line);
            persons.push_back(p);
        }
    }
    file.close();
    /*Show vector persons with a simple for*/
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read the line and split it with the comma delimiter and use the QStringList `QStringList list = mystring.split(',');' now you can iterate your csv elements from the `QStringList` something like `list.at(0)'